# deleting specific duplicate and original entries in a table based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

i have a table called "main"  which has 4 columns, ID, name, DateID and Sign.

i want to create a query that will delete entries in this table if there is the same ID record in twice within a certain DateID.

i have my where clause that searches the previous 3 weeks

```
 where DateID =((SELECT MAX( DateID)
                                WHERE DateID < ( SELECT MAX( DateID )-3))
```

e.g of my dataset im working with:

| id | name | DateID | sign |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Paul | 1915 | Up |
| 23658 | Danny | 1915 | Down |
| 37868 | Jake | 1916 | Up |
| 37542 | Elle | 1917 | Up |
| 12345 | Paul | 1917 | Down |
| 87456 | John | 1918 | Up |
| 78563 | Luke | 1919 | Up |
| 23658 | Danny | 1920 | Up |

in the case above, both entries for ID 12345 would need to be removed.
however the entries for  ID 23658 would need to be kept as the DateID > 3

how would this be possible?

Comment: Please don't provide columns as rows, it makes things difficult to understand (and makes your data look denormalised). IF you want to display your data, use a markdown table or well formatted tabular `text` please.

Comment: As for the question, I would suggest looking at `LAG`; there isn't enough (consumable) sample data for me to make an attempt here.

Comment: thanks larnu, i had a look at the LAG function. it seems to work to catch the duplicate value if i order by ID, however, how would i also get the original to be deleted?

Comment: Like I said, we don't have enough information.

Comment: ok , what other info could i provide? this is a table with just those 4 columns and it updated hourly, i just want to catch any duplicate ID's within a certain time frame and remove both the duplicate and original record?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Starting by fixing your sample data will be helpful. More than 2 examples, with different scenarios is also helpful, as users who answer don't want the goal posts moving after they've answered, due to unspecified requirements (which I can see this one having).

Comment: ok thanks all for that, i have corrected the sample data and better explained it. hopefully that makes more sense. apologies this is my first post

Comment: max duplicate is 2?

Comment: @Hana yes you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions for this.

It's not quite clear, but it seems `LAG` and conditional `COUNT` should fit what you need.

```sql
DELETE t
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      CountWithinDate = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.PrevDate >= t.DateId - 3 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.id)
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
          PrevDate = LAG(t.DateID) OVER (PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY t.DateID)
        FROM YourTable t
    ) t
) t
WHERE CountWithinDate > 0;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=54af97bf647a96001799dbb0484d95c6)

Note that you do not need to re-join the table, you can delete directly from the `t` derived table.

Comment: this also works . many ways to skin a cat! thanks charlieface for that, some great learning for me

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works:

```
DELETE FROM test_tbl
WHERE id IN (
                SELECT T1.id
                FROM test_tbl T1
                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test_tbl  T2 WHERE T1.id = T2.id AND ABS(T2.dateid - T1.dateid) < 3 AND T1.dateid <> T2.dateid)
            )
```

In case you need more logic for data processing, I would suggest using Stored Procedure.

Comment: perfect that works exactly as needed. thanks a million Hana!